# \newgeometry introducing a blank page into document

Tags: geometry

I've seen similar questions on here but solutions don't seem to work.

Basically I am trying to input a figure into my document in the middle of the page without worrying about margins.  What I have is

```
\newgeometry{margin=0cm}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
        \vspace*{\fill}
            \begin{figure}[h!]
                \centering
                \includegraphics{Fig}
                \label{Fig}
                \captionsetup{textformat=empty,labelformat=blank}
                \caption{Fig}
            \end{figure}
        \vspace*{\fill}
    \restoregeometry
```

Also note that I do not want this figure to have a caption, but to be shown in the list of figures, thus the \captionsetup stuff - in my preamble I have `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{blank}{}`

A blank page is being output directly before the page containing this figure. `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig}` does not work to eliminate this.

So I guess is there either a fix for this problem, or is there a way to delete a blank page?

Comment: `\newgeometry` always introduces a new page

Comment: Is the figure just too wide or also too high? In any case, `\newgeometry` is the wrong tool to use.

Comment: The figure is the correct size.  What tool should I be using?

Comment: That's something I would also really like to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `p` option of  `figure` environnement:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{Fig}
\label{Fig}
\captionsetup{textformat=empty,labelformat=blank}
\caption{Fig}
\end{figure}
```

The `p` environnement will put your figureS in one page. If you have only one figure to input then you are ok.